# Block messages from non-friends

Tags: origin

I've got a couple chat messages in Origin, and they are all spam. E.g;

> ◆Fifa 14 coins Service on 24/7 in *removed website*
> ◆Full Stock for Xbox/PS3/PS4/PC/IOS/ANDROID.
> ◆Buy Fifa 14 coins Deliver in 5 Minutes
> ◆More Cheap  Fifa 14 coins 100% Security Guarantee!
> ◆Fast Delivery and Low Prices!
> ☆☆☆Shop Now!☆☆☆
> ★★★ *removed website* ★★★

There is a notification at the top of the chat window that states (this is verbatim, yes, the English is broken);

```
is not on your friends list.
```

So; is there any option within Origin to block, or at least not receive notifications for, messages from users not in your friends list?

Answer (score 2):

Visit the site on a PC. Then download Origin. On the bottom of the page, you'll see a list of your friends. When you click on one, you should be allowed to block them. Also in the "My Account" section, there should be a tab for Privacy Settings. Here you can block users. Hope this helps :D

Source:http://tstoforum.com/thread/4100/origin-friends-lists-blocking-users

Comment: spammers, being what they are, use multiple accounts. That settings screen doesn't have an option to block messages from all non-friends, but does let you block individuals who aren't friends

Comment: I only gave the upvote because blocking spammers *after* they've already messaged me eliminates none of the hassle

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure if there's another way to do it.